# "Operation not implemented yet" Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, export

I have an asp.net web application. When I try to export a report via crystal report I get following error :

`Error in File C:\DOCUME~1\User\LOCALS~1\Temp\MainReport {7F8A9E9E-DD47-4D17-A44D-68D9478A792C}.rpt: Operation not yet implemented.`

I use this code to export report :

```
    ReportDocument reportDocument = reportSource.ReportDocument;
    reportDocument.SetDataSource(dt);
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders(); 
    reportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, false, "Report");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Does your report have non-standard fonts?  If so, that could be the problem.  See [link text](http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=1050)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, I found the description of the problem in :

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3102429

The solution of the problem can be found at:

https://blog.brankovucinec.com/2015/12/10/kb3102429-causes-crystal-report-export-to-pdf-to-fail/

Notes:

- This problem occurs when you use a DataSet as a source of report data. Sql queries and StoredProcedures this error did not happen
- This problem occurs when you will export the report to PDF using a DataSet as a data source, if you try to export to Excell and Word this does not happen.

You must remove this update from your computer or server (if this problem).

> 1: Go to Control Panel
>
> 2: Select View installed updates
>
> 3: Search the KB3102429 update, And Then select Uninstall.

**If you can not uninstall this update:**

Issue only manifests with export to PDF using DataSet (Word and Excell not affected), only if the report contains TNR or Arial (no other fonts found to cause a problem but not every font was tested) and only with the versions of fonts, if you change the fonts on your report to SergoeUI your report (maybe) will work.

Comment: Excellent.  This resolved an issue for me with an application using CR 10.5 (not my app).  One measly text field in Arial on the report, everything  else is TNR... somebody missed a field I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and was fixed by removing Microsoft's latest update KB3102429. This is an optional update and you can safely remove it from your machine.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems exporting to PDF when there is a version conflict or when the Adobe software isn't installed on the computer. CR talks directly to the Adobe DLLs and they need to be compatible. In the past few years, Adobe has released so multiple versions of their Acrobat software (versions 6-8). It can be tricky.

Or another Solution again create new crystal report and replace with old one

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Update for Microsoft Windows(KB3102429 and KB3104002)

> Control Panel –> Program & Features –> View installed updates and
>   Search for KB3102429 and KB3104002 right click and uninstall.

Comment: I only uninstalled KB3102429 and it resolved this issue for me

Answer (score 0):

I've got same issue recently. The source of the problem was in latest windows updates (Win 2008). I've found that standart FONTS (Arial, Times New Roman, etc.) was updated. So i copied older versions of these fonts from my windows 7 machine and installed it over on windows 2008. After that PDF export start working again.